# Should I use "Most of which" or "Some of them"?

Tags: adjectives, clauses

Afghanistan is estimated to have 73 million tons of coal reserves, ... are located in the northern part of the country.

Comment: What are your concerns, and have you looked up the two phrases to understand how they differ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is your concern? Is it 'most' versus 'some' or 'which' versus 'them'? If, as I suspect, it is the latter, then I should say that 'them ' is wrong in this context. 'Them' implies a countable number of things, but coal reserves are just geological masses of coal - 73 million tons in this case. Having stated that figure the word 'most' will be understood by the reader to refer to 'tons of coal' not individual geological concentrations of coal. It (probably) does not make sense to count them.

I inserted 'probably' because if you look at things on a large enough scale then you can count some reserves. For example, if you believe that rubies can be mined in South Africa and in Thailand, but nowhere else on earth, then you could say 'There are two reserves of rubies. One of them is in Thailand'.

Answer (score 1):

The use of  “Most of which” or “Some of them” depends on the question of How many?

You are talking about the 73 million tons of coal reserves. If less than 31.5 million tons are in the northern part of the country then “Most of which” is not correct. Then you would say “Some of them”. You can understand these by thinking of 100%, 99% 51% as All (100%), nearly all or most(99%), and most (51%). Then you are left with some (49% to 1%) and less than 1% as few or nearly none.